# Python Count Method: Can It Accept Object Attribute References?

Tags: python, oop, object, count

I built a simple poker game in Javascript a while ago and thought I'd start it from scratch in Python. Here's the code thus far (you can skip to the end for the issue):

```
#imports
import random
#basics
values = range(2,15)
suits = ['Clubs','Spades','Diamonds','Hearts']
#card object
class Card:
    def __init__(self,suit,value,name):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value
        self.name = name
        if self.value < 11:
            self.name = str(self.value) + ' of'
        if self.value == 11:
            self.name = 'Jack of'
        if self.value == 12:
            self.name = 'Queen of'
        if self.value == 13:
            self.name = 'King of'
        if self.value == 14:
            self.name = 'Ace of'
#deck
deck = []
#load and shuffle deck
for s in suits:
    for v in values:
        deck.append(Card(s,v,'o'))
random.shuffle(deck)
#load hands
your_hand = random.sample(deck,7)
for card in your_hand:
    deck.remove(card)
#determine hands
def find_matches(hand):
    class Match:
        def __init__(self,value,amount):
            self.value = value
            self.amount = amount
    matches = [Match(card.value,hand.count(card.value)) for card in hand]
    for x in matches:
        print x.value,x.amount
find_matches(your_hand)
```

Yes, I realize it isn't perfect (suggestions are always appreciated!). My issue is making a reliable match-finding function. I've tried a few different approaches, but with this one `hand.count(card.value)` comes out as 0 for each element. Is the issue with what parameters the count method will accept? Or is it with an aspect of my code?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with `hand.count(card.value)`is that it counts how many`Card` objects in the hand are equal to the integer value of one of them, which will always be zero because your comparing two different objects. A simple fix would be to just extract all the integer card values into a separate list and use the`count()`method of that instead:

```
def find_matches(hand):
    class Match:
        def __init__(self, value, amount):
            self.value = value
            self.amount = amount
    values = [card.value for card in hand]  # list of extracted card values
    matches = [Match(card.value, values.count(card.value)) for card in hand]
    for x in matches:
        print x.value, x.amount
```

With this change, it'll do something like this:

```
10 1
4 1
9 1
3 1
12 2
12 2
6 1
```

A more Pythonic way to do something similar would be to use a`collections.Counter`class with a generator expression:

```
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter(card.value for card in your_hand)
print '{} unique values: {}'.format(len(counter), counter)
```

Which for the same hand would give you:

```
6 unique values: Counter({12: 2, 3: 1, 4: 1, 6: 1, 9: 1, 10: 1})
```

I think this would be easier for you to use when evaluating the hands (it's a dictionary subclass).

Comment: I was using something quite similar earlier, but I wanted a more pythonic way of expressing it. Still, it's good to know why my current method isn't working - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`hand.count(card.value)` will check how many times `card.value` appears in the deck. That's 0 because the value is a number and there are no numbers, only `Card`s, in the deck.

You can do `sum(card.value == 5 for card in hand)` to get the number of cards in `hand` where `card.value == 5`. This works because `a == b` has a boolean value, `True` or `False`, which are numerically equal to `1` and `0` respectively.

So it iterates through the hand (`for card in hand`), makes the comparison (`card.value == 5`) and sums up the number of `True`s, although it does it inline so a list is stored in memory.

Answer (score 2):

Your question was answered well, so here are some other comments:

First, the snaky chain of `if`s in `Card.__init__()` is better replaced by a dictionary lookup.  Like do:

```
value2name = dict((val, str(val)) for val in values)
for val, name in (11, 'Jack'), (12, "Queen"), (13, "King"), (14, "Ace"):
    value2name[val] = name
```

after you set `values`, and then replace all the `__init__()` cruft with:

```
        self.name = value2name[value] + " of " + suit
```

Then `some_card.name` will display as (for example):

```
King of Spades
5 of Spades
Ace of Hearts
[etc]
```

Second, if you use `random.shuffle()`, there's no point to **also** using `random.sample()` - or vice versa.  Use just one.  Since you'll probably want to peel off other hands later, `shuffle()` is better.  After shuffling the deck, 7 random cards can be removed from the deck very efficiently like so:

```
your_hand = deck[-7:]
del deck[-7:]
```

Deleting a slice from the **end** of a list is very efficient in CPython.  In effect, the implementation just records that the list's size is now smaller by the number of elements deleted - nothing needs to be rearranged.

To get another 7 cards, just do the same.  Or put it in a function:

```
def deal(deck, n):
    if n <= 0:
        raise ValueError("n must be > 0")
    if n > len(deck):
        raise ValueError("asked for more cards than remain")
    result = deck[-n:]
    del deck[-n:]
    return result
```

and then:

```
your_hand = deal(deck, 7)
```

later.

Have fun! :-)